# How to redirect an URL with %0 and blank spaces in it using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to 301 redirect a URL that has both spaces and an encoding error (`%0` which causes a 400 error) in it using an htaccess rule.

So far I tried these without luck:

```
RewriteRule ^page%20with%20\x0issue$ https://target.com/target-url [R=301,L]
```

```
RewriteRule ^page\ with\ \x0issue$ https://target.com/target-url [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: give actual link

Comment: The `%20` should have already been decoded into spaces again already at this point. _“`%0` which causes a 400 error”_ - I am not sure if you still _can_ catch this at that point; the error might have been raised already and caused the web server to break off further processing of the request, so that it never even gets to the point where your .htaccess could affect anything.

Comment: @04FS Yeah, that might be the case. I'm not sure... Was hoping my rules are just off.